# A problem related to intersecting lines

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

if I save some line equations (y=ax+b) in the following way for each line, with two points:
(0,b),(1,a+b), and none og them intersect with another, for example:

$y=x+1 -> (0,1),(1,2)$

$y=x+2 ->(0,2),(1,3)$

$y=x+3 ->(0,3),(1,4)$

$y=2x-1 -> (0,-1),(1,1)$

and want to add another line, only if it doesn't intersect with my previous lines between $0<=x<= 1$
for example I want to add y=6x-1 ((0,-1),(1,5))
why is it enough to check if it intersects with the predecessor/successor in y value?
for example, here it is enough to check it with  y=x+1

Comment: $y=6x-1$ intersects $y=2x-1$ at $(0,-1),$ so it seems to me that it is **not** enough to check it with $y=x+1.$ Where did you get this problem, what else was said about it that you haven't told us, and why do you think it is "enough to check if it intersects with the predecessor/successor in y value"?

Comment: By the way, the object consisting of two endpoints and all the points on the straight line between them is a **line segment**, not a **line** in most geometry textbooks. If you were actually talking about **lines** then any two lines with different slopes would intersect.

Comment: This problem is much more difficult than you think.

Answer (score 0):

This is a brutal question, but I enjoyed doing it quite a lot.

Let’s say the new line to be added is $$y=mx + c $$
which has two parameters. We’ll find out the set of solutions of $m,c$ that satisfy the given conditions.

Firstly,  get the $x$-coordinate  the point of intersection of this new line with the previous lines:
$$L_1 :\ x=\frac{1-c}{m-1} \\ L_2: x=\frac{2-c}{m-1} \\ L_3: x= \frac{3-c}{m-1} \\ L_4: x=\frac{1+c}{2-m}$$
where $L_1, L_2, L_3, L_4$ are lines respectively in the order specified in the question.
Now, we need *each* of these intersection abscissas to lie outside of the interval $[0,1]$, which is equivalent to saying

$$ x \gt 1\, \vee \, x\lt 0$$ in each case. Applying this condition yields $4$ different conditional inequalities in $m$ and $c$ which we must take the intersection of. Simplifying these we get the following:

$$\bullet \space m+c \lt 2 \, \vee \, (c \gt 1 \wedge m \gt 1)$$

$$\bullet \space m+c \lt 3 \, \vee \, (c \gt 2 \wedge m \gt 1)$$

$$\bullet \space m+c \lt 4 \, \vee \, (c \gt 3 \wedge m \gt 1)$$

$$\bullet \space m+c \gt 1 \, \vee \, (c \lt -1 \wedge m \lt 2)$$

It should be fairly easy to solve these inequations graphically. Here’s a very rough picture for the solution set. Note the $x$ and $y$ axes represent $c$ and $m$ respectively.

[image]

The yellow region is the solution set.

We can infer from the graph that the solution set is as follows for $m,c \in \mathbb R$:

$$ ( m \lt 2 \wedge c \lt -1)\, \vee \,
   ( 2 \lt m+c \lt 3 ) \, \vee \, (m \gt 1 \wedge c \gt 1 \wedge m+c \lt 3) \, \vee \, (m \gt 1 \wedge c \gt 2 \wedge m+c \lt 4) \, \vee \, (m \gt 1 \wedge c \gt 3)$$